# Dont validate input when FilteringSelect loses focus

Tags: validation, dojo, focus, widget

Im using Dojo 1.5 to create a widget involving a FilteringSelect. It doesnt use autoComplete so the user is free to input what they like. By default it seems that when it loses focus it validates the content and displays the error message.

How can I customise it so that when the input loses focus it doesnt validate the content?

Comment: What's the point of having a FilteringSelect if you want to let the user type things that are not part of your list ???

Answer (score 0):

Just use the *dijit.form.ComboBox* instead.